# Mysql check empty rows of child elements

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have a query to select all childs (positions) based ob the parent id (order_id):

```
SELECT * FROM positions WHERE order_id = X
```

The result looks like:

```
ID | order_id | checked_1 | checked_2
1  |    1     |  J. Doe   |  M. Doe
2  |    1     |           |  Mr. Tester
3  |    1     |  J. Joe   |
```

Now i need a query to check if the fields checked_1 & checked_2 are not empty of all related childs. So if all fields of the childs are filled, there shoulbe be appear a success notice in frontend.

What is the best way to "migrate" all childs, so that i can afterwards create the php query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May try this to count if empty value is there:

```
SELECT count(*) AS count_empty FROM positions 
WHERE order_id = X AND (IFNULL(checked_1, '') = '' OR 
IFNULL(checked_2, '') = '')
```

So now, if count_empty is zero you may show the success message.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Work great!

Comment: welcome! Please accept as answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 'SUCCESS' as '' FROM postions WHERES orderid = x AND (checked_1 IS NOT NULL OR checked_1 = '') AND  (checked_2 IS NOT NULL OR checked_2 = '');
```

Answer (score 0):

We can aggregate here by order, and then check for the presence of an empty `checked_1` or `checked_2` column, for a given `order_id` group.  You may try the following query:

```
SELECT 
    order_id,
    CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(checked_1, '') = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
              SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(checked_2, '') = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
         THEN 'valid' ELSE 'invalid' END AS status
FROM positions
WHERE order_id = 1
GROUP BY order_id;
```

Note that I don't know if the missing values are `NULL` or actually just empty string.  My query covers for both possibilities, but if these missing values be `NULL` then you can remove my calls to `COALESCE`.  Also, you may remove `GROUP BY` if you plan on only running this query for a single `order_id`.  Though should you have the need to run the query for multiple orders at a time, what I wrote above should come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do this:

`select MIN(CASE WHEN checked_1 = '' OR checked_2 = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) from positions group by order_id`

You will get a '0' if any field is empty or '1' if all are <> ''.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f7518d/1